# How to get Rhythmbox running on another user account to see the audio CD I inserted?

Tags: sound, ssh, rhythmbox, cd

I have inserted an audio CD. I have also logged into another account on the same machine through `ssh -X`.

I can successfully launch Rhythmbox, but it doesn't see the CD I have inserted, even though it is visible in my main account.

How can I convince Rhythmbox that a CD has been inserted? I already tried 'Scan for Removable Media', but that didn't work.

---

**Update:** VLC can see and access `/dev/cdrom` but Rhythmbox cannot.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to add your user to the 'cdrom' group. `System > Admin > Users and Groups` provides a handy GUI app.

Comment: I did... and I'm afraid that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will work, but you can try disabling the CDRom Lock like so:

```
sudo bash -c "echo dev.cdrom.lock=0 >>/etc/sysctl.conf"
```

Comment: Finally got around to trying this, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Rhythmbox as the user that inserted the CD by running `gksu -u userwhoinsertedthecdcausetheyaresoawesomeandsuchlike rhythmbox`

(for example: `gksu -u george rhythmbox`). This should allow rhythmbox to see the CD. If all else fails, you might have to unmount the CD from the first user account, and then allow the second account to automount it when you switch again.

Comment: Wait... which user inserted the CD? The one physically logged in, or the one logged in via SSH?

Comment: @George Edison the one physically logged in should be the one :)

Comment: If I run Rhythmbox under *that* account, then that defeats the whole purpose... I'm trying to rip a CD using the other person's account.

Comment: @George - Well, best thing I can think of us to rip with one account and then move the files and do a `chown` on them?

Comment: *That* is a possibility. But I would prefer to not have to do it that way.